# Getting cookie value in php

Tags: php, cookies

I am setting a cookie in `PHP` using this code

```
// file1.php
$email = 'abc@xyz.com';
setcookie('songs_email',$email,time() + (86400 * 30));
```

I checked in browser cookie I found it there with name `songs_email` .
But when I try to retrieve this cookie using this code

```
// file2.php
echo $_COOKIE["songs_email"];
```

I am getting these notice.

```
// file2.php
Notice: Undefined index: songs_email in C:\wamp\www\practise\login.php on line 12
```

In **file1.php** if I write `echo $_COOKIE['songs_email']` then I am getting the value. But in **file2.php** I am not getting it.

Can any1 please tell me what is the problem. I will be thankful to you.

**Guys guys please help!! Got so many views but not getting any solution**

---

**I tried the same code in another PC. It is working fine. But why it is not working in my PC**

Comment: Use `echo isset($_COOKIE["songs_email"]) ? $_COOKIE["songs_email"] : "Not Set";` Are you sure the cookie is being set ? What does `$email` contain ?

Comment: You are checking whether it is available or not. But I am sure it is available. and if I do `echo $_COOKIE['songs_email']` I should get the value of `songs_email`. But I am not getting it.

Comment: your code is right, but follow sequence....first declare cookie then only display it...Are you doing right this?

Comment: yes , I am doing like this only

Answer (score 0):

Calling `setcookie` will apply it to future requests, but it doesn't add the new cookie to the `$_COOKIE` superglobal. You have to do this yourself. Nice and simple: `$_COOKIE['songs_email'] = $email;` but it does need to be manual if you want to access it in the current request.

Comment: Using `setcookie('songs_email',$email,time() + (86400 * 30));` I am setting the cookie

Comment: where `$email='abd@xyz.com'`

Comment: Yes, but if you're trying to access it in the same request, it won't be there.

Comment: But it is available in browser cookie list

Comment: Is that on the "response cookies", or the "cookies sent"?

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you explain more. Please

Comment: @D'Scolz, Read about the [**Common Pitfalls of cookies**](http://in2.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#refsect1-function.setcookie-notes)

Answer (score 0):

This is solution for it pass in single quote.echo $_COOKIE['songs_email'];

You are passing it in this way $_COOKIE["songs_email"]; pass it in single quote like this $_COOKIE['songs_email'];

Comment: I tried it on my side it is not giving me such error when pass it in single quote.

Comment: Try with double quotes,I think it also won't give you error.

Comment: But don't know I am not getting it. I have tried in different browser also

Comment: If i passed it with double quotes it gives me error but when i passed in single quote then working fine in both browser(Firefox and chrome).

Comment: O. . that's nice. But I am not getting with any one. :(

Comment: Try with double quote at all three places.

Comment: No . Facing the same problem